# Two-factor authentication was working using .now code but after i changed my chromedriver version, does not work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password

I used topt.now for my automation code. It was working fine for signing in but as soon as i updated Chromedriver to 76, the opt part stopped working. The authentication is wrong now. Any feedback. Is there any relationship with Chromedriver version for totp?

```java
public static String getotp(String secretkey) {
    // secretkey argument is second factory authentication key
    Totp totp = new Totp(secretkey);

    return totp.now();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code used to configure and create the instance of ChromeDriver?

Comment: And which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: There is only one version of joss aerogear which is 1.0,0

Comment: Check for clock sync issues between the client and the server

Answer (score 0):

Two Factor Authentication has no connection with the chromedriver version. 
`Totp` is responsible for generating the code.

The moment you `return` the code from your method, the role of `Totp` is over.

Please make sure your secret key, time after which it is regenerated and the number of digits in the key match the authenticator.

Also, Totp requires a Base32 Encoding. So you shouldn't pass the string in the `compute` method. Convert the key into bytes and then send it

Comment: There has been a update to the dependency. That was the issue, but even after my build is compiled and m2 is generated. Still getting a error